# How to get GIT-HTTP-BACKEND working? (Apache)

Tags: windows, git, apache, server

I wrote this to `http.conf`

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT "C:\xampp\htdocs\git\"
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-http-backend.exe"
```

When I start apache, normal files open as is but `\git\ pages return 403 forbidden`.
[attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJteN.png)

And git doesn't clone such a repository over http.